# exception: "java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Enum not an enum" during deserialization

Tags: java, exception, jackson

I trying to solve problem I faced during desrialization of EnumSet with jackson.

I have en EnumSet created like

```
EnumSet set = EnumSet.of(TestEnum.Value1, TestEnum.Value2, TestEnum.Value3);
```

And during deserialzation  get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Enum not an enum
    at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(EnumSet.java:93)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumSetDeserializer.constructSet(EnumSetDeserializer.java:123)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumSetDeserializer.deserialize(EnumSetDeserializer.java:88)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumSetDeserializer.deserialize(EnumSetDeserializer.java:18)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2575)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1805)
    at com.easycompany.providers.serialization.impl.jackson.base.JacksonSerializationProviderBase.readString(JacksonSerializationProviderBase.java:339)
    at com.easycompany.tests.serialization.base.ReadWriteStringTestBase.read(ReadWriteStringTestBase.java:33)
    at com.easycompany.tests.serialization.base.ReadWriteStringTestBase.action(ReadWriteStringTestBase.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Could anyone help me with the way how to fix that?

***Solved by me**: if intrested read my answer below.*

Comment: You're going to have to post your actual code or no one can help you fix it.

Comment: Was a bit hard to place the code there now, because it spread across several generic classes. But sometimes just asking the right question already helps you to find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already found the solution myself. The problem is that in method `EnumSet.noneOf()` need to pass concrete enum type (in my case TestEnum), but I'm calling it through a bunch of generic functions and as result in code it just know that it need to construct enum, but don't know which enums it should constract. Using jackson reader with valid type referenced params solve the problem.

Comment: +1 This is what I suspected, but without seeing your actual objects I couldn't be sure.